# Django Updating A one To Many Array

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

So I get this error
Direct assignment to the reverse side of a related set is prohibited. Use emails.set() instead.

This is how my code looks like

```
class Client(models.Model):

class Email(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='emails', null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=50)

class EmailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Emailfields = '__all__'

class ClientSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    emails = EmailSerializer(required=False, allow_null=True, many=True)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        # Update all fields of Client.
        [setattr(instance, k, v) for k, v in validated_data.items()]
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

So the client can have many emails. When update is called, it says Direct assignment to the reverse side of a related set is prohibited. Use emails.set() instead.

This error message can be avoided by removing the emails from the validated_data via let emailsData = validated_data.pop('emails', []).

but once done, im not sure what to do next in order to update the emails array if it needs updating, or deleting it if it is not in the emailsData array anymore.

json looks like this

```
{ id: 10, name: 'test', emails: [ { id: 1, emailType: 'Work', email: 'test@gmail.com', client_id: 10 } ] }
```

and i have this form where you can add/remove email fields if a client has more than 1 email. so if i add another email row, without setting an email address, the array gets sent to the json including it. so in django, i check if email is empty, do not insert.

this works ok when creating. but then, my dilemna is during update. if the email id is the same, update it, else if 0, insert. i also need to detect which email fields to delete if the user decided to remove one of his existing email addresses.

the easiest would be to just delete all and recreate email entries based on the array but i do not want that as i do not want the id counter to be wasted.

Thoughts?

Comment: There are quite a few things wrong with your code here, eg the use of a list comprehension for its side effects. But why do you think you need to define `update` at all? The default implementation should work fine.

Comment: the json data always has an emails array where 2 properties are always not null. so im looking at the 3rd property as the basis , if it's empty, then do not insert. if i did not define update(), it will always try to save an email entry

Comment: Then it sounds like you need to define validation. Please show an example of the data and explain the result you want.

Comment: hi daniel, i updated the post.